# {AHK} Defining controls (/Assigning tasks) for those GUI buttons that were creted after script launch

Tags: autohotkey

Lets say with some action during running script, you create gui with several buttons via Loop.

```
    Loop, 5
{
Gui, Add, Button,, Number %A_Index%)
}
Gui, Show
```

How do u then assign actions upon pressing one of buttons?

It seems you cant do it after script launch, and tricks like

```
ButtonNumber%A_Index%:  ;even if i was doing it inside loop.
do something here bla bla
return
```

do not work.

To do things even worse, i wanted to created these buttons (here for test) from contents of a file, say, each lines text gets utilized to name a button.
you can find similar mini-projects in AHK help files. Buts lets stick with this simple analog.
May be:
Storing and Responding to User Input, third option Variable or g-label is the anwser. Yet it asks for static/global var, but i have troubles declaring these. And g-labels i am not familiar with.

Other option i had in mind is- creating pre-defined buttons (a lot), rename them to my values (from file), and discard rest. hopefully i will be able to use predefined controls.

**P.S**
AHK help file is a real mess, as a beginner i find it pretty had to fish out complete and meaningful information, instead you have to search and take a bite here and there.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a parsing loop and one g-label for all the buttons, then use A_guiControl to get the variable name of the button that called the sub-routine

**Example:**

```
; fileread, file_content, Path-to-file
file_content =
(
line with text one
line with text more
line with text other
line with text something
line with text two
)

Loop, parse, File_content, `n, `r
{
    Gui, Add, Button, vMyButton%A_index% gButtons, %A_LoopField%
}
Gui, Show
return

Buttons:
msgbox % A_GuiControl
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have found one possible anwser to my problem. Basicly it involves g-label functionality that **blackholyman** (lel) suggested.
Using same g-label for all my buttons combined with A_GuiControl comparison inside button control.
Since i have stored buton names in a file, in one line with other data, that is relevant for this button, i can compare each line, by parsing, with button name (A_GuiControl), thats makes me able to retrieve relevant data inside assigned g-label.
May be some one will find it useful. Ill add code later.